# paintComponent method doesn't draw on the JPanel in the RMI browser

Tags: java, swing, drawing, rmi, paintcomponent

I'm working on an RMI browser project.
Which has two interfaces Service and ServiceServer.
Three Classes ServiceServerImpl(Server), ServiceBrowser(Client), and DiceTester.

The ServiceBrowser (Client) calls the class DiceTester which implements the Service (Interface) which returns a serialized JPanel to the ServiceBrowser.

The ServiceBrowser adds the JPanel sent by the DiceTester, and even adds the JButton and JComboxBox, but when it calls the paintComponent method it doesn't draw anything on the Clients Browser.

ServiceServer Interface Code.

```java
    import java.rmi.Remote;
    import java.rmi.RemoteException;
    
    public interface ServiceServer extends Remote {
        Object[] getServiceList() throws RemoteException;
        Service getService(Object serviceKey) throws RemoteException;
    }
```

ServiceInterface

```java
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.io.Serializable;

public interface Service extends Serializable {
    JPanel getGUIPane();
}
```

ServiceServerImpl (Server)

```java
import java.rmi.Naming;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class ServiceServerImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements ServiceServer{
    HashMap serviceList;

    public ServiceServerImpl() throws RemoteException{
        setUpServices();
    }

    private void setUpServices(){
        serviceList = new HashMap();
        serviceList.put("New Dice Rolling Serivce", new DiceTester());
    }

    @Override
    public Object[] getServiceList() throws RemoteException {
        System.out.println("in remote");
        return serviceList.keySet().toArray();
    }

    @Override
    public Service getService(Object serviceKey) throws RemoteException {
        return (Service) serviceList.get(serviceKey);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            Naming.rebind("com.headfirstjava.ServiceServer", new ServiceServerImpl());
//Please remove the package name or change it accordingly.
        } catch (Exception Ex){
            Ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

ServiceBroswer(Client)

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.rmi.Naming;

public class ServiceBrowser {
    JPanel mainPanel;
    JComboBox serviceList;
    ServiceServer server;

    private void buildGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("RMI Browser");
        mainPanel = new JPanel();

        Object[] services = getServiceList();

        serviceList = new JComboBox(services);
        serviceList.addActionListener(new MyListListener());

        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH, serviceList);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, mainPanel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private Object[] getServiceList() {
        Object obj = null;
        Object[] services = null;

        try {
            obj = Naming.lookup("rmi://127.0.0.1/com.headfirstjava.ServiceServer");
////Please remove the package name or change it accordingly.
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        server = (ServiceServer) obj;

        try {
            services = server.getServiceList();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return services;
    }

    class MyListListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Object selection = serviceList.getSelectedItem();
            loadService(selection);
        }
    }

    private void loadService(Object serviceSelction) {
        try {
            Service svc = server.getService(serviceSelction);

            mainPanel.removeAll();
            mainPanel.add(svc.getGUIPane());
            mainPanel.validate();
            mainPanel.repaint();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ServiceBrowser().buildGUI();
    }

}
```

DiceTester

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Objects;

public class DiceTester implements Service {
    static final long serialVersionUID = -7720503853902873983L;

    int i = 0;
    private static final int RECT_Y = 120;
    private static final int RECT_HEIGHT = 100;
    private static final int RECT_WIDTH = 100;

    JPanel mainPanel;
    JPanel diceTestPanel;
    JComboBox selection;

    @Override
    public JPanel getGUIPane() {
        mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel componentPanel = new JPanel();
        diceTestPanel = new MyDrawPanel();

        String[] choices = {"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"};
        selection = new JComboBox(choices);

        JButton button = new JButton("Roll 'em!");
        button.addActionListener(new RollTestListener());

        componentPanel.add(selection);
        componentPanel.add(button);
        mainPanel.add(BorderLayout.NORTH,componentPanel);
        diceTestPanel.add(new MyDrawPanel());

        mainPanel.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, diceTestPanel);

        return mainPanel;
    }

    class RollTestListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            mainPanel.repaint();
            System.out.println("Done");
        }
    }

    class MyDrawPanel extends JPanel {
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            int RECT_X = 10;
            String number = (String) selection.getSelectedItem();
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            for (int x = 0; x < Integer.parseInt(Objects.requireNonNull(number)); x++) {
                g2d.setColor(new Color(0x0A0A0A));
                g2d.fill3DRect(RECT_X, RECT_Y, RECT_WIDTH, RECT_HEIGHT, true);

                int r = (int) ((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
                switch (r) {
                    case 1:
                        g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                        g2d.fillOval(RECT_X + 36, RECT_Y + 36, 25, 25);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                        g2d.fillOval(RECT_X + 20, RECT_Y + 36, 25, 25);
                        g2d.fillOval(RECT_X + 55, RECT_Y + 36, 25, 25);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                        g2d.fillOval(RECT_X + 15, RECT_Y + 20, 25, 25);
                        g2d.fillOval(RECT_X + 60, RECT_Y + 20, 25, 25);
                        g2d.fillOval(RECT_X + 37, RECT_Y + 50, 25, 25);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                        g2d.fillOval(RECT_X + 15, RECT_Y + 15, 25, 25);
                        g2d.fillOval(RECT_X + 60, RECT_Y + 15, 25, 25);
                        g2d.fillOval(RECT_X + 15, RECT_Y + 60, 25, 25);
                        g2d.fillOval(RECT_X + 60, RECT_Y + 60, 25, 25);
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                        g2d.fillOval(RECT_X + 15, RECT_Y + 15, 20, 20);
                        g2d.fillOval(RECT_X + 60, RECT_Y + 15, 20, 20);
                        g2d.fillOval(RECT_X + 37, RECT_Y + 37, 20, 20);//CenterDot
                        g2d.fillOval(RECT_X + 15, RECT_Y + 60, 20, 20);
                        g2d.fillOval(RECT_X + 60, RECT_Y + 60, 20, 20);
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                        g2d.fillOval(RECT_X + 15, RECT_Y + 10, 20, 20);
                        g2d.fillOval(RECT_X + 60, RECT_Y + 10, 20, 20);

                        g2d.fillOval(RECT_X + 15, RECT_Y + 42, 20, 20);//CenterDot
                        g2d.fillOval(RECT_X + 60, RECT_Y + 42, 20, 20);//CenterDot

                        g2d.fillOval(RECT_X + 15, RECT_Y + 75, 20, 20);
                        g2d.fillOval(RECT_X + 60, RECT_Y + 75, 20, 20);
                        break;
                }
                RECT_X += 120;
            }


            System.out.println("paintComponent done");
        }
    }
}
```

To run compile all the classes in let's say "classes" directory.

1. cmd rmiregistry and make sure it has access to the classes.
2. In another terminal java ServiceServerImpl.
3. In another terminal java ServiceBrowser.

Should be open in the order given above else fails.

[image: GUI]

Comment: [mcve] please..

Comment: @kleopatra Is it good now?

Comment: yeah, with a bit of tweaking (doesn't compile as-is due to implementing Service and the override annotation ;) - but don't understand what you expect: your paintComponent isn't implemented to do anything (except logging), so what should it draw?

Comment: if I let it draw a line, f.i., I see two lines: one from the outer, one from the inner MyDrawPanel .. just what I would expect :) And can't reproduce your last sentence, that is no repaint triggered when clicking/selecting the combo. Please be sure that your code really demonstrates the problem ..

Comment: 1) When doing custom painting you need to override the `getPreferredSize()` method of the panel so layout managers can work properly. 2) Why are you creating two instances of "MyDrawPanel" and attempting to add the component to itself? 3) Read the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and complete working examples.

Comment: @kleopatra I was trying not to make it too long, but here's everything you need.
Please compile the code, and enlighten me on why it's not drawing.

Comment: @camickr Can you too please look at the code and tell me what's wrong?

Comment: does the painting work as expected if not sent over rmi? If so, you might be doing something wrong (not familiar with that aspect, so can't help you): your best bet might be doing some basic debugging, like sending a plain panel without custom painting, do some very simple custom painting .. and see when it stops working as expected.

Comment: @kleopatra Yes, it does work fine if not sent over RMI.
Ok, I'll try debugging it.

Comment: @kleopatra Can you tell me why someone downvotes my Question?
Is it because too long or....?

Comment: @camickr Thanks, Overriding the ```getPreferredSize()``` Method solves the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, So, I'm actually reading this book "Head first java", and that was an exercise.
A similar program was in the book.
So I figured it out.
And @camickr also suggested doing that.

we have to override the `getPrefferedSize()` Method as @camickr also advised.

```java
            public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
            return new Dimension(600,300);
        }
```

[image: Output After overriding the method]

Comment: *I'm actually reading this book "Head first java"* - and don't forget the Swing tutorial for examples/explanations of most Swing basics.

Comment: @camickr noted.